# Excess space on div element

Tags: html, css

So I had this excess space on div element containing my button. And for some reason there is this excess space in the bottom.

It seems like my display flex is doing it? Im not entirely sure. If the flex thing doing it, how do I solve it? should I remove the flex?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

div#Calculator {
  width: 320px;
  height: 620px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

div#inputs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
}

div#inputs #inputVal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div#buttons {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

div#buttons div button {
  padding: 28px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Calculator">
  <div id="inputs">
    <input id="inputVal" value="">
  </div>

  <div id="buttons">
    <div> <button class="operators"> + </button> </div>
    <div> <button class="operators"> - </button> </div>
    <div> <button class="operators"> x </button> </div>
    <div> <button class="operators"> ÷ </tton> </div>
    <div> <button id="erase"> C </button> </div>
    <div> <button class="numbers"> 1 </button> </div>
    <div> <button class="numbers"> 2 </button> </div>
    <div> <button class="numbers"> 3 </button> </div>
    <div> <button class="numbers"> 4 </button> </div>
    <div> <button class="numbers"> 5 </button> </div>
    <div> <button class="numbers"> 6 </button> </div>
    <div> <button class="numbers"> 7 </button> </div>
    <div> <button class="numbers"> 8 </button> </div>
    <div> <button class="numbers"> 9 </button> </div>
    <div> <button class="numbers"> 0 </button> </div>
    <div> <button id="equal"> = </button> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I already saw similar questions and tried the solutions of it and none of them seems to work like setting the padding and margin to 0 which I always do or setting the button on display block.

Please pardon me if this kind of question has been answered here already.

Comment: Try not to use `id` as CSS selector

Comment: do you consider using the grid view instead of the flex one ?

Comment: @Andy I havent study grid yet

Comment: @Raptor Can you tell me why is that? yhey also said that use id only for js.

Comment: For CSS, it's better to use class selectors. For JS, you can use id selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the excess space effectively. Now, it will cover the entire viewport height and if you want to change the width just use `div#Calculator`'s width and everything else will follow it. I changed the height, width and the margins to the viewport units so that the contents are fully responsive and also removed the unnecessary codes.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div#Calculator {
    /* This is the total width (When you want to change the width just change this one and everthing will adjust) */
    width: 40vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div#inputs #inputVal {
    height: 19vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5vh;
}

div#buttons {        
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: -1%;
    margin-left: -1%;
}

div#buttons div {
    width: 23%;
    margin: 0.5vh 1%;
}

div#buttons div button {
    height: 19vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Calculator">
    <div id="inputs">
      <input id="inputVal" value="">
    </div>

    <div id="buttons">
      <div> <button class="operators"> + </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="operators"> - </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="operators"> x </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="operators"> ÷ </tton> </div>
      <div> <button id="erase"> C </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="numbers"> 1 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="numbers"> 2 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="numbers"> 3 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="numbers"> 4 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="numbers"> 5 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="numbers"> 6 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="numbers"> 7 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="numbers"> 8 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="numbers"> 9 </button> </div>
      <div> <button class="numbers"> 0 </button> </div>
      <div> <button id="equal"> = </button> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

***Hi,***

this excess space come truly from flex, but it is a normal behaviour of it.

---

### What is the problem?

Your div `Calculator` has a constant height and Your `inputs` container has 80% of its height. All of your inputs "need" less as this 80% height of this container, so redundant space is simple divided as empty spaces between the rows.

---

### Solution

*Edit: added second solution*

I don't know Your exact intention, so I propose 2 solutions.

1. When You not set the container div `Calculator` constant height, then Your `Calculator` will have height of the whole content (but You must then another set the `inputs` height - % works no more in this case).
2. Not setting the `buttons` height. That let the `inputs` have its 20% height of container and the rest of Ypur calculator will be fine expect the container which will take much more space than needed (or it is Your intention to have this 620px).

Below is an updated snippet of your code with 1. solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Simple Calculator </title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Calculator.css"/> -->
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }


    body {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    div#Calculator {
        width: 320px;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap; 
    }

    div#inputs {
        width: 100%;    
        height: 15%;
    }

    div#inputs #inputVal {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    div#buttons {
        height: 80%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    div#buttons div button {
        padding: 28px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="Calculator">
        <div id="inputs">
            <input id="inputVal" value="">
        </div>  

        <div id="buttons">
            <div> <button class="operators"> + </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="operators"> - </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="operators"> x </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="operators"> ÷ </tton> </div>
            <div> <button id="erase"> C </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 1 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 2 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 3 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 4 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 5 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 6 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 7 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 8 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 9 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 0 </button> </div>
            <div> <button id="equal"> = </button> </div>
        </div>

    </div>




<script type="text/javascript" src="Calculator.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here below is an updated snippet of your code with 2. solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Simple Calculator </title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Calculator.css"/> -->
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }


    body {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    div#Calculator {
        width: 320px;
        height: 620px;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap; 
    }

    div#inputs {
        width: 100%;    
        height: 15%;
    }

    div#inputs #inputVal {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    div#buttons {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    div#buttons div button {
        padding: 28px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="Calculator">
        <div id="inputs">
            <input id="inputVal" value="">
        </div>  

        <div id="buttons">
            <div> <button class="operators"> + </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="operators"> - </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="operators"> x </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="operators"> ÷ </tton> </div>
            <div> <button id="erase"> C </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 1 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 2 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 3 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 4 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 5 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 6 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 7 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 8 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 9 </button> </div>
            <div> <button class="numbers"> 0 </button> </div>
            <div> <button id="equal"> = </button> </div>
        </div>

    </div>




<script type="text/javascript" src="Calculator.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Knowledge

From the basic concept of flexbox described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox):

> [..] a one-dimensional layout model, and as a method that could offer space distribution between items [...].

in short and in very simplification - dealing with redundant space in a container for items is an exact thing of flexbox. Of course there are more possibilities to manage empty spaces and items displaying, but in this case we talk about dividing an excessive space.

---

***Cheers***

Answer (score 0):

add `align-content: center;` to #buttons selector in css or check the align-content property of css [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-content.php)

Answer (score -3):

```css
div#Calculator {
  width: 320px;
  height: 620px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

div#inputs {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* Adjusted height */
}

div#buttons {
  height: auto; /* Adjusted height */
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

div#buttons div button {
  padding: 28px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```